# Data Binding not working in Angular, why?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am learning Angular now. And i am just stuck in a Data binding concept. I have wrote below code in 2 file. But it won't work.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(){}
  name = 'Rakesh';
  ngOnInit(){
  } 
  changeMyTitle() {
    this.name = 'Rocky';
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
 <p>My name is {{ name }} </p>
" Here is a Button code in Html calling changeMyTitle()"
```

Comment: Are you just looking for `<button (click)="changeMyTitle()">Change Name</button>`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind `click` event to your button and invoke `changeMyTitle()` defined in your component.

Just use this in your HTML:

```
<p>My name is {{ name }} </p>
<button (click)="changeMyTitle()">Change name</button>
```

here is [the stackblitz with working example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dmpgyu)

Comment: yes, i have used that but it still won't display the name. First of all i just want to display on paragraph. What should i do to display name? I have searched that in many area. But no luck. So finally i wrote here.

Comment: See the stackblitz for the working example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dmpgyu